# selecting max values

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I've created the below query to retrieve various Client and Matter information for my 
law firm. - Essentially we need to see who has worked on which matter(s) for which 
client(s) in the last three years.

In addition to the Matter Creation Date, we've now been asked to retreive the 
Transaction Date - TT.TRAN_DATE  - (billed hours) which will let us see who has worked 
on something recently with a much greater degree of accuracy. Problem is that there 
will be multiple transaction dates for each client/matter/fee earner and we only 
really need to see the most recent transaction date.

Unfortunately I'm struggling and time is short. Can someone tell me how I can modify 
the above query so that only the maximum transaction date will be returned for each 
client / matter / fee earner? The date should also be in the same format as the 
existing 'Matter Creation Date' field.

Thanks in advance, Gavin

```
SELECT DISTINCT HC.CLIENT_NAME AS [Client Name],
  HC.CLIENT_CODE AS [Client Code],
  HM.MATTER_CODE AS [Matter Code], 
  HM.CLNT_MATT_CODE AS [Client Matter Code],
  convert(varchar,HM.OPEN_DATE,103) AS [Matter Creation Date],
  HP.EMPLOYEE_CODE AS [Fee Earner Code],
  HP.EMPLOYEE_NAME AS [Fee Earner Name],
  TT.TRAN_DATE AS [Transaction Date]
  FROM        HBM_MATTER HM  
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TAT_TIME TT 
        ON    HM.MATTER_UNO=TT.MATTER_UNO
  LEFT JOIN   HBM_CLIENT HC 
        ON    HM.CLIENT_UNO=HC.CLIENT_UNO 
  LEFT JOIN   HBM_PERSNL HP 
        ON    TT.TK_EMPL_UNO=HP.EMPL_UNO 
  WHERE             HM.INACTIVE='n' 
  AND         HM.STATUS_CODE <> 'CLOSE'
  AND         HP.INACTIVE = 'N'
  AND         TT.TRAN_DATE > dateadd(month,-36,getdate()) 
  ORDER BY    HC.CLIENT_CODE,   HM.MATTER_CODE
```

Comment: Is this in SQL server?

Comment: Apologies - Yes, SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server because you didn't specify, this is my solution. I can't check it but I think it should be OK:

```
    WITH cte AS (SELECT DISTINCT 
      HC.CLIENT_NAME AS [Client Name]
      ,HC.CLIENT_CODE AS [Client Code]
      ,HM.MATTER_CODE AS [Matter Code]
      ,HM.CLNT_MATT_CODE AS [Client Matter Code]
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR,HM.OPEN_DATE,103) AS [Matter Creation Date]
      ,HP.EMPLOYEE_CODE AS [Fee Earner Code]
      ,HP.EMPLOYEE_NAME AS [Fee Earner Name]
      ,TT.TRAN_DATE AS [Transaction Date]
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY HC.CLIENT_CODE, HM.MATTER_CODE, HP.EMPLOYEE_CODE 
                          ORDER BY TT.TRAN_DATE DESC) AS trans_order 
    FROM HBM_MATTER HM  
      LEFT OUTER JOIN TAT_TIME TT ON HM.MATTER_UNO=TT.MATTER_UNO
      LEFT OUTER JOIN HBM_CLIENT HC ON HM.CLIENT_UNO=HC.CLIENT_UNO 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN HBM_PERSNL HP ON TT.TK_EMPL_UNO=HP.EMPL_UNO 
    WHERE HM.INACTIVE = 'n' 
      AND HM.STATUS_CODE <> 'CLOSE'
      AND HP.INACTIVE = 'N'
      AND TT.TRAN_DATE > DATEADD(MONTH, -36, GETDATE()) 
   )
    SELECT * FROM cte 
    WHERE trans_order = 1
     ORDER BY 
      CLIENT_CODE
      ,MATTER_CODE
```

Comment: Thanks for that. That seems very close but I'm seeing the errors

Comment: Exceded maximimum time to edit the above comment. That solution seems very close but I'm seeing the binding errors: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "HC.CLIENT_CODE" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "HM.MATTER_CODE" could not be bound.       If I remove the 'ORDER BY' clause it's fine?

Comment: @gavin nichol Need remove alias from ORDER BY clause and possible remove DISTINCT operator too.

Comment: Sorry still had the ORDER BY columns scoped as though they were in the main query - edited and should now be OK.